# Is there a WinSplit Revolution style window manager for Ubuntu Unity (11.10)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, window-manager, ubuntu-unity

I'm giving Ubuntu a whirl, and I'm using the Unity desktop.

I'd like to be able to resize / reposition my windows using the keyboard (something like Windows has with [WinSplit Revolution](http://winsplit-revolution.com/) (e.g. `Ctr+Alt+NumPad6` moves window to right side of screen so it takes up 1/2 the screen, etc.).

What would be a good choice for this? I found [these window managers](http://xwinman.org/), but they're not applicable to Unity, right?

Also, while Googling I've come across references to the "Unity Window Manager" but I can't find this application. Do they just mean Unity itself... where are the instructions for the window management commands (commands like the example I gave above for WinSplit Revolution)?

Comment: Unity uses Compiz, which *is* listed on xwinman. You can replace Unity's window manager using `compiz --replace`. Beware, though, that odd errors have been known to come out of such an operation - see [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1758768) for some issues you might have.

Comment: @new - Thanks for that link. It's a good place to start and has some very helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same key combination works in Ubuntu 11.10 using Unity 3D (not sure about Unity 2D). Place focus on the desired window then press and hold CTRL + ALT + any of the numpad keys. You can position the window in any corner or even center of screen. Repeated use of the same number will resize the window while keeping it in the desired screen corner.

Unity Window Manager should be short for Unity.

Ubuntu Geek has a short list of keyboard shortcuts that you might find useful: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/list-of-ubuntu-unity-keyboard-shortcuts.html. As an alternative you can install the CompizConfig Settings Manager, either from the Ubuntu Software Center or from the command prompt (sudo apt-get install ccsm), and dig through the Ubuntu Unity Plugin, and other plugins for that matter, to learn the other shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu 13.10 you can easily replicate the functionality of WinSplit Revolution using built in tools.

By default Ubuntu 13.10 allows Ctrl + Alt + Numpad shortcuts for repositioning windows, however it has fixed sizes for these - eg Ctrl + Alt + Numpad4 moves the window to half-left.

You can however enable window size cycling. First you'll need Compiz Settings Manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then launch it, go to Window Management > Grid > Resize Actions and enable "Cycle Through Multiple Sizes" et voila! Perfect WinSplit revolution functionality :)